# If statements with 2 conditions in VBA

Tags: vba

On Error Resume Next

```
    j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Strg, ws2.Range("K1:K3100"), False)
    result = Cells(j, 21)

If (Err <> 0) Then
  Else

    If result = "Closed" Then
       Cells(j, 3) = "B"
       ws1.Select
       Cells(i, 22).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red

      'copy row to the other tab

       Rows(i).Select
       Selection.Copy
       ws3.Select
       Rows(k + 2).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       k = k + 1
       ws1.Select
    End If
```

Need to add one more if statement after Cells (j,3) = "B"
condition would be in the column A (year) is 2016 color the cell in different worksheet (ws1.select) in the column Employee ID to Orange.

Comment: Do you want it nested or do you want it added so that two conditions must be met for if to be true?

Comment: year 2016 must be met true for any employee found

Comment: so you want `if result = "closed" and year = 2016 then` or do you want `if result = "closed" then do this` and after that check `if year = 2016`?

Comment: want the second one and color the employee id which is ws1 worksheet.. thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this -

```
If result = "Closed" Then
       Cells(j, 3) = "B"
       ws1.Cells(i, 22).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red

       If Cells(i, 1) = 2016 Then
        ws1.Cells(x, y).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 'you need to specify where Employee ID column is with replacing x and y
       End If

      'copy row to the other tab
       For Each c In ws1.Rows(i)
        ws3.Cells(k + 2, c.Column) = c
       Next

       k = k + 1

    End If
```